# Confused about SQL Server procedure to rename constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Alright I'm brand new to SQL Server and I have a script to rename constraints in a database to abide by naming standards. I would just like it explained because I'm very confused.

```
IF @PrimaryKeys = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT @sql = @sql + @cr + @cr + '/* Primary Keys */' + @cr;
    SELECT @sql = @sql + @cr + 'EXEC sp_rename @objname = ''' 
    + REPLACE(name, '''', '''''') + ''', @newname = ''PK_' 
    + LEFT(REPLACE(object_name(parent_object_id), '''', ''), @TableLimit) + ''';'
      FROM sys.key_constraints
      WHERE type = 'PK'
      AND is_ms_shipped = 0;
END
```

The part I'm most confused about is the `replace(name, '''', '''''')`. I know that it's taking a string, finding something in it, and replacing that something, but I don't understand all of the single quotes.

Comment: Notice there are 2x more apostrophe's. Double them up to print out one. The outcome will be 'PK_constraint'

Comment: `''''''` evaluates to a string "''". Two single quotes is encoded notation that represents a single quote "'" value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is generating something called 'Dynamic SQL' and storing it in a variable.  It's concatenating together several strings, columns, and other things into a single long text value.

SQL Server, though, understands a text value as something that starts and ends with a single quote (apostrophe).  If you need to pass a single quote into that text value (like here), you actually have to type out two quotes together - SQL will understand then that you're not trying to indicate the start or end of a text string, but instead want to keep the apostrophe.

So, your REPLACE() function is stuffing in extra apostrophes so that your column's name (e.g., "O'Laughlin") will be read by the concatenation as "O''Laughlin" and then be understood to actually represent the value "O'Laughlin".

Comment: Right, so in that case what is the replace function doing? Taking the name of the constraint and doing what to it? Say the original constraint is PK_MyTable_172833 and the naming standards want it to be PK_MyTable. Why would the replace function be replacing quotations with more quotations when there aren't any in the names in the first place? Please let me know if I'm being absolutely empty-headed.

Comment: The REPLACE function is taking the name of the constraint and adding it to the string (@SQL).  Just in case that constraint's name contains an apostrophe, which would break the dynamic SQL script by falsely telling SQL that the string has ended, any apostrophes that happen to be in the name of the constraint are escaped so that the string knows to just include them.

Answer (score 2):

It replaces single quotes with double quotes:

```
before after
------ -----
it's   it''s
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you read it better. Hope it helps. As for the stuff with quotes, Probable you have PK's with single Quotes in and to pass it as an input parameter, all single quotes would need to be repeated once.

Try this assign this sting to a variable **This won't work**

```
DECLARE @testStr VARCHAR(50)

SET testStr = 'This won't work'
SET testStr = 'This won''t work'
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) =''
DECLARE @cr VARCHAR(20) = CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
DECLARE @PrimaryKeys INT = 1
DECLARE @TableLimit int =10

IF @PrimaryKeys = 1
    BEGIN 
    SELECT @sql = @sql + @cr + @cr + '/* Primary Keys */' + @cr; 
    SELECT @sql = @sql + @cr + 'EXEC sp_rename @objname = ''' + REPLACE(name, '''', '''''') + ''', @newname = ''PK_' + LEFT(REPLACE(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id), '''', ''), @TableLimit) + ''';'
                                                         FROM sys.key_constraints
                                                         WHERE type = 'PK'
                                                           AND is_ms_shipped = 0;
    END
PRINT @sql
```